# Add A 1-D Numpy Array to DataFrame as a Row

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Is there a function which allows you to efficiently append a NumPy array directly to a DataFrame?

Variables:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

Out[1]: +------+------+------+
        | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
        +------+------+------+
        |      |      |      |
        +------+------+------+


arr = np.empty(3)

# array is populated with values. Random numbers are chosen in this example,
#    but in my program, the numbers are not arbitrary.
arr[0] = 756
arr[1] = 123
arr[2] = 452

Out[2]: array([756, 123, 452])
```

How do I directly append `arr` to the end of `df`to get this?

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  756 |  123 |  452 |
+------+------+------+
```

I've tried using `df.append(arr)` but it doesn't accept NumPy arrays. I could convert the NumPy array into a DataFrame then append it, but I think that would be very inefficient, especially over millions of iterations. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Use

    `df.loc[len(df)] = arr`

Comment: @rafaelc that's going to slow to a crawl very quickly. it starts to take 10ms per row once your at 100K rows and there's another 900K+ to go

Comment: @ALollz but not one said there was a for loop and we were appending at every iteration

Comment: can you give more information about how you're generating these numbers? Likely the best solution is going to be to preallocate everything, fill it accordingly and then construct the DataFrame at the end.

Comment: I was surprised there is no easy way to append a line of data frame into another data frame!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@BalrogOfMoira is that really faster than simply creating the dataframe to append?

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape(1,-1), columns=list(df)), ignore_index=True)
```

Otherwise @Wonton you could simply concatenate arrays then write to a data frame, which could the be appended to the original data frame.

Comment: It's useful if the DataFrame already exists and populated with data.

Answer (score 6):

This will work:

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(arr).T)
```

Comment: It doesn't work if column index are integer(and column indexes do not start from zero). It adds column with index from zero the smallest index in df.columns, and assign the arr value only to the first len(arr)-th elements.

Answer (score 4):

@rafaelc comment can work only if your Pandas DataFrame is indexed from 0 to len(df)-1, so it is not a general workaround and it can easily produce a silent bug in your code.

If you are sure that your Numpy array has the same columns of your Pandas DataFrame you could try using the *append* function with a dict comprehension as follows:

```
data_to_append = {}
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    data_to_append[df.columns[i]] = arr[i]
df = df.append(data_to_append, ignore_index = True)
```

You need to reassign the DataFrame because `append` function does not support in-place modification.

I hope it helps.