# Add many 1-D array to dataframe as a row?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am new to python and I want to know how to add many 1-D array to dataframe as a row. I have look into the previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292901/add-a-1-d-numpy-array-to-dataframe-as-a-row) but it is a bit different in my case. Here is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
arr = np.empty(3)
arr[0] = 756
arr[1] = 123
arr[2] = 452
```

let's say this answer work well:

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape(1,-1), columns=list(df)), ignore_index=True)
```

But when I wanted to add another 1-D array in the same dataframe:

```
a = np.empty(3)
a[0] = 700
a[1] = 100
a[2] = 400
df.append(pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(1,-1), columns=list(df)), ignore_index=True)
```

I got the empty dataframe. What wrong with it? How can I add many 1-D array in general? Any help would be much appreciated!

My desire output:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  756 |  123 |  452 |
+------+------+------+
|  700 |  100 |  400 |
+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign `df`:

this:

```py
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape(1,-1), 
                            columns=list(df)), ignore_index=True)
```

The complete code then becomes:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
arr = np.empty(3)
arr[0] = 756
arr[1] = 123
arr[2] = 452
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape(1, -1),
                            columns=list(df)), ignore_index=True)
a = np.empty(3)
a[0] = 700
a[1] = 100
a[2] = 400
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(1, -1),
                            columns=list(df)), ignore_index=True)
print('Result: ')
print(df)

# A bit more efficient though:
arr = np.empty((2, 3))
arr[0, 0] = 756
arr[0, 1] = 123
arr[0, 2] = 452

arr[1, 0] = 700
arr[1, 1] = 100
arr[1, 2] = 400

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], data=arr)
print('\nSame result, but more efficient : ')
print(df_2)
```

Comment: I try this: ``` df = da.append(pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(1,-1), columns=list(df)), ignore_index=True)``` it did not work it print the last array 2 times

Comment: Could you please check again, I did not see that behaviour. I added the complete code now instead of only the crucial line.